# How does `ls -lh` round file size?

Tags: linux, unix, ls

I'm comparing the rounded file size value displayed by `ls -lh` to the raw size in bytes (as displayed by `ls -l`, say).  I'm having a hard time figuring out what algorithm it uses to do the conversion from bytes.

My assumption is that it interprets the units K,M,G as either

- (a) 10^3, 10^6, 10^9, or
- (b) 1024, 1024^2, 1024^3.

On the one hand, I have one file that `ls -l` reports as 2052 bytes, and `ls -lh` rounds to 2.1K:

```
$ ls -l usercount.c 
-rw-r--r-- 1 squirrel lsf 2052 May 13 15:41 usercount.c
$ ls -lh usercount.c 
-rw-r--r-- 1 squirrel lsf 2.1K May 13 15:41 usercount.c
```

This would seem to support hypothesis (a), because 2052/1000=2.052 which rounds up to 2.1K but 2052/1024=2.0039 which clearly would display as 2.0K when rounded to one decimal place.

On the other hand, I have another file that `ls -l` reports as being 7223 bytes, which `ls -lh` displays as 7.1K:

```
$ ls -l traverse.readdir_r.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 squirrel lsf 7223 Jul 21  2014 traverse.readdir_r.c
$ ls -lh traverse.readdir_r.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 squirrel lsf 7.1K Jul 21  2014 traverse.readdir_r.c
```

This confusingly supports hypthesis (b), because 7223/1000=7.223 which should round down to 7.2K, but 7223/1024=7.0537 which rounds up to the displayed 7.1K

This leads me to conclude that my assumption is wrong and that it does neither (a) nor (b) exclusively.  What algorithm does `ls` use to do this rounding?

Comment: Interestingly, a file of 1999 and 2099 both show as 2.0K

Comment: Try looking at the source

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU ls will by default *round up* in *1024*-based units.

It does not round to nearest, as you've taken for granted.

Here's the formatting flag from [gnulib human.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/human.h#n48):

```
/* Round to plus infinity (default).  */
human_ceiling = 0,
```

This is consistent with everything you're seeing:

- 2052 is 2.0039 KiB which rounds up to 2.1
- 7223 is 7.0537 KiB which rounds up to 7.1

Answer (score 1):

by default the block size in ls is 1024, but for example if the output is 44.203125k it will round it to 45k
you can change it too

```
ls -lh --block-size=1000
```

and the source code: [ls source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't think block size really effects how it decides to round the numbers.  Rather, it just tells to give you the smallest number of blocks of the given size bytes that would contain the file.

Answer (score 0):

To list just file name and it whole size:

```
ls -s --block-size=1
```

And this is a bit simplified version, list files in column:

```
ls -x -s --block-size=1 *.*
```